# Configuring a Windows Protocol in a VS2010 Deployment Project

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry, protocols

I have an application that is called in a command line fashion.  I wish to associate a protocol with it, let's call that protocol `runapp`. `runapp` will call `runapp.exe`.

I plan to have this configured through the Registry portion of the application Deployment Project.  I started by looking at other protocols, specifically `mailto`.  I noticed that I need the following:

- a new key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` called `runapp`
- a new series of keys to create `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\runapp\shell\open\command`
- under the `runapp` key, I will add two strings, `(Default)` with value `URL:runapp protocol` and a second string `URL Protocol` and no value
- also under the `command` key, I need to add one string, `(Default)` with value `"C:\path\runapp.exe" "%1"`

I set all these up just fine.  When I actually run the installer, though, before my `(Default)` strings, there is already another valueless `(Default)` string.  So it looks like I am settings a `(Default)` string in the wrong way.  What's the right way?

Secondly, I manually hacked this incorrect key in regedit after backing everything up.  Now, with my keys looking very much like `mailto`'s, I finally stop getting the "No program found" error, but my application actually doesn't seem to execute at all.

Any thoughts on how to correctly set `(Default)` strings and further troubleshoot protocol issues?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually using "(Default)" as the value name? If so, that is probably your problem.

Comment: But you can't just leave it blank either.  If you don't set it it becomes `New Value #N`.   So how then can I mimic the setting of a string called `(Default)`?

Comment: I have not done an install project in a while, but I know in code with RegSetValueEx(), you use NULL or "" to set the default value.

Comment: Check out this link. It explains how to provide a default value in an installer project. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266441(v=vs.60).aspx#vehowsettingregistryvaluesanchor2

Comment: Ahh, if I just delete the string name it actually correctly becomes `(Default)`.  Thanks!